# Правильный перебор массива

Tags: php, база-данных

Колонки в БД: id | who, id уникален. Суть такая: допустим, у нас есть айди 1,3,5 с ником nick и айди 2,4,6 с ником name, не могу перебрать массив так, чтобы выводились все записи, где who=`nick`.

**Дополнено.**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from messages WHERE who=`nick`");
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rows   = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $rows; $i++) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from messages WHERE who=`nick` and id='$i'");
    $myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $who    = $myrow['who'];
    echo $who;
}
```

Выводит много пустых полей, т.к кроме Nick есть и другие ники и запрос не выполняется, нужно получить id каждой записи и подставить как-то в цикл, чтобы выводились все записи где who=nick, без всяких пустых полей.

Comment: хоть бы привели для примера код который не могу...

Comment: @angers777, Пожалуйста, уточните, что Вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что за извращение в дополнении! Вот этого достаточно чтобы вывести `id`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from `messages` WHERE `who`='nick'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['id']." ";
}
```

---

Чуточ ликбеза не повредит вашей психике:

```
SELECT * from `messages` WHERE `who`='nick'
```

Этим запросом вы сделали половину дела, из таблицы `messages` вы выбрали те записи у которых колонка `who` содержит значение `nick`, и вернули в ответ записи со всеми колонками, т.е. `who` и `id`:

```
id | who
---------
1  | nick
3  | nick
5  | nick
```

Вам же нужно было только `id`, т.к. `who` как ни крути нам известен, можно было обойтись запросом:

```
SELECT `id` from `messages` WHERE `who`='nick'
```

далее загружаемся в PHP, в переменной `$result` ресурс запроса, который нужен для других функций php-mysql
Функция `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` возвращает **один** ряд из результатов запроса, у нас 3 ряда. Под циклом `while` потому что перебираем все ряды, если ряды закончатся то и цикл закончится, и каждый раз переменной `$row` возвращаем один ряд. Если с[дамп](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php)ить $row получися:

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'who' => string 'nick' (length=4)
```

Из этого выводим айди `$row['id']` добавив пробел `." "`
p.s.: Советую тебе учить сразу расширение mysql**i**, просто mysql сейчас не в тренде

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос непонятен.
Зачем перебирать какой-то массив, если речь идёт о базе данных?
Это делается одним запросом:

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE who = 'nick'
```

Если же вопрос именно о массиве, то опять же не вижу проблемы:

```
foreach($arr as $data) {
    if ($data['who'] == 'nick')
       _вывести_данные_    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможные решения, которые помогают в типичных случаях:

1. mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
2. where `who`='name';
3. `foreach($fetched_array as $key=>$value){ if($key=='name'){/*Магия*/}}`

Рассматривать по-отдельности.

Comment: А зачем использовать mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC), если есть mysql_fetch_assoc($result)? :)

Comment: Потому что привык так. На производительности или читабельности это не сказывается.